# Why does OS X kill a process immediately executed in the terminal?

Tags: sql, macos, go

Weird error I'm getting attempting to run migrations from a CLI on my OS X.

When I attempt to run a migration it immediately kills the process.

I'm using golang's [goose](https://github.com/steinbacher/goose) package to migrate up and I run `goose create CreateUsers` and I immediately get

`[1]    18990 killed     goose create CreateUsers`

I've also tried running [sql-migrate](https://github.com/rubenv/sql-migrate) with `sql-migrate up` which is the same thing but from a different package and I get the same error.

In fact, if I shorten the commands to just `goose` for example, I run into the same problem.  Bad install possibly?

I have created the databases and can access them.

**Note**

I'm looking for an explanation of why this might happen.  Not necessarily package-specific, but more of a reason why Mac decides to terminate the process immediately.

**Additional Note**

Looks like it's a package error.  It was a fork of a fork and the original package relies on a different version of golang.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode update caused a problem with loading a core library in golang. Solution: update golang to 1.8.1

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19734

Comment: Use the most recent version. Besides the obvious bug fixes, you're missing some security fixes too.

Comment: I am using that version now.  But the version that fixed this particular bug is 1.8.1.